# Estoy creando un List<Pedido> pero los datos del lugar [0] se sobreescriben C#

Tags: c#

Como bien dice el titulo, estoy haciendo una lista con la clase Pedido, pero cuando hago `.Add()` los datos en el lugar `[0]` se sobreescriben

```
List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>(); 

 string[] imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(@"wwwroot\imgAndroid\", "*.jpg");

     foreach(var img in imagenes)
     {
           string[] rutaSplit = img.Split("\\");
           string[] imagenRecuperada = rutaSplit[2].Split("_");
    
           if(numeroPedido != "" && numeroPedido == imagenRecuperada[0])
           {
                pedido.setNumeroPedido(numeroPedido);
                pedido.setNumeroEntrega(imagenRecuperada[1]);
                pedido.setNumeroRemito(imagenRecuperada[2]);
                pedido.setimagenes(img);
                listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
            }                    
    }
```

Esta es la imagen la primera vez que entra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ésta es la segunda vez que pasa por el `foreach`

La posición `[0]` cambia el `name` "imágenes"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no aporta nada a la comunidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta instanciar `new` el objeto Pedido que quiero agregar, sino siempre estoy agregando la misma instancia de la clase

```
foreach(var img in imagenes)
{
    string[] rutaSplit = img.Split("\\");
    string[] imagenRecuperada = rutaSplit[2].Split("_");

     if(numeroPedido != "" && numeroPedido == imagenRecuperada[0])
     {
          pedido = new PedidoViewModel(); //Faltaba ésta linea  
          pedido.setNumeroPedido(numeroPedido);
          pedido.setNumeroEntrega(imagenRecuperada[1]);
          pedido.setNumeroRemito(imagenRecuperada[2]);
          pedido.setimagenes(img);
          listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
       }                  
}
```

Comment: ah no me habia dado cuenta que es tu pregunta.. queres explicar un poco mas que paso?

Comment: Simplemente eso! Cada vez que recorria en el foreach no instanciaba un new PedidoViewModel(), por eso se me sobreescribia!

Comment: si.. yo lo se.. vos lo sabes.. la respuesta asi como esta es mala y es solo codigo y no explica el problema...

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que, como te explicaban, estabas sobreescribiendo las variables y metiendo las mismas en la lista, por lo que siempre metes las mismas variables pero con diferente valor. De ahí que en la posición [0] veas cambiar el valor pero que no se agreguen nuevos elementos.
Si pasas algo más de código, por ejemplo la parte de la clase en la que tienes declaradas las variables, podemos echarte una mano a que el código sea óptimo.

Un saludo.